# How do I avoid read locks in my database?

Tags: sql, database, performance, locking

How do I avoid read locks in my database?

Answers for multiple databases welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle the default mode of operation is the *Read committed* isolation level where a select statement is not blocked by another transaction modifying the data it's reading.
From [Data Concurrency and Consistency](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c21cnsis.htm):

> Each query executed by a transaction sees only data that was committed before the query (not the transaction) began. An Oracle query never reads dirty (uncommitted) data.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server you can use the with(nolock) keyword in your select statements.  For example:

```
Select table1.columna, table2.columna
from table1 with(nolock), table2 with(nolock)
```

Make sure to specify with(nolock) for each table/view in the query.

Comment: Which means you read `uncommitted` data with possible disastrous results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686724/sql-when-should-you-use-with-nolock/686733#686733 Often this is not a problem, especially with the 'new' snapshot features, but you have to be aware of the consequences: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/deadlocked.html

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL also uses MVCC (Multi-Version Concurrency Control), so using the default transaction isolation level (read-committed), you should never block, unless somebody is doing maintainace on th DB (dropping / adding columns / tables / indexes / etc).

Answer (score 2):

In Firebird writers never block readers and there are no dirty-reads. Only read-commited and snapshot isolation levels.
It uses a multi-generational engine (like oracle i believe) instead of simple page or record locking.