# Execute a SQL Server stored procedure with different input parameter on a thread via C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to execute a SP which is having 2 input parameters multiple times (say 100 times) on a thread/parallely. I have added Asynchronous Processing=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true in my connection string and using below code to execute the SP

On button_Click

// ExecuteSPList is a List having list of having 100 ReportID and on button click I am creating thread 100 times which is calling CallInvokeUpdate

```
           Parallel.ForEach(ExecuteSPList, itm =>
            {
                CallInvokeUpdate(itm.ToString());
            });
```

Then in CallInvoke:

```
   public void CallInvokeUpdate(string str)
   {
       ExecuteSP(str, strSelectedMonthEndDate);
   }
```

And finally ExecuteSP method.

```
   public string ExecuteSP(string ReportId)
   {
       try
       {
           string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString;               

           DataSet ds = new DataSet();

           using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
           {
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateExecuteSP", sqlConnection);
               sqlConnection.Open();
               cmd.CommandTimeout = 3000000;

               addParameter(cmd, "ReportId", ReportId, SqlDbType.Int);

               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

               IAsyncResult result = cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
               cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
           }
           return "OK";
       }

       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw;
       }
   }

   private void addParameter(SqlCommand cmd, string name, object value, SqlDbType type)
   {

       SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter(name, type);

       cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

       parameter.Value = value;
   }
```

My problem is that if execution of stored procedure "UpdateExecuteSP" takes 5 secs for one 
ReportId then using this approach also it is taking somewhere around 100*5 = 500 secs.

Can any one suggest how to reduce this time and run the SP 100 times parallely. There is no dependency between any execution.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I would start from making your DB call of stored proc a static method. Then manage multi-threading around that

Comment: the two most likely reasons are: SPs are locking tables and cant run in parallel or you are capping out your hard drive IO.

Comment: @Tsabo I fount out that after executing the SP its locking the tables in DB. does that mean that until locks are not released next processing won't happen. Pls note that the records affected by param1 which is paaded to SP is altogether different from the param2, param3 and so  on . Pls suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is locking tables, to execute SP's in parallel you will need to change the Isolation level in your SPs.

One way to do this is like this:

```
.....
FROM dbo.TableName with (nolock)
.....
```

Note, that this can lead to unexpected behavior, but I think that as long as no 2 parallel queries modify the same rows it should be good. Please read this thread to learn more about the method

[When to use with (nolock)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686724/sql-when-should-you-use-with-nolock)