# Configure the isolation level to allow ReadUncommited while updating data

Tags: c#, sql, .net, transactions, isolation-level

I begin a transaction with `SqlConnection.BeginTransaction()` and I do a `DELETE` and some `INSERT`s. There is any configuration I can do on the isolation level to allow any query to read the data on a "dirty way" during the transaction?

Basically I want to prevent locks while I update the data. The problem is; I can't control the `SELECT`s. If I define a `ReadUncommited` isolation level on my transaction will the external querys have rights to read the data without waiting or is required to define it on this querys?

For example:

```
try
{                         
   connection.Open();
   transaction=connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommited);            

   // DELETE
   foreach (int i in fibarray)
   {
       // INSERTS
   }
   transaction.Commit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   if (transaction.Connection != null)
       transaction.Rollback();
}
```

Meanwhile, the `SELECTS` on another machine I have not the access.

Comment: Each connection/session establishes for itself what level of dirtiness it's willing to put up with. There's no way for a *different* connection to suddenly force a connection to see dirtier data (or, conversely, to be more strict)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So there is no way to tell my update commands not to block. It depends entirely on the "`SELECT`s" side.

Comment: Yes, the `SELECT`s have all of the control over their locking/blocking behaviour. And `UPDATE`s always have to apply some exclusive locks to complete successfully.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well, that was the information I was asking for, so if you don't mind add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each connection/session establishes for itself what level of dirtiness it's willing to put up with. There's no way for a different connection to suddenly force a connection to see dirtier data (or, conversely, to be more strict)

The `SELECT`s have all of the control over their own locking/blocking behaviour. And `UPDATE`s always have to apply some exclusive locks to complete successfully. So if you cannot change the `SELECT`s, then you can't overcome your current situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try `WITH(NOLOCK)` clause on the other `SELECTS`. This clause will read dirty data.

Example

```
SELECT ....
FROM <tablename> WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE ......
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686724/sql-when-should-you-use-with-nolock)

EDIT:
BTW, setting the isolation level ReadUncommited will make the current transaction read uncommitted data, it doesn't control the isolation level of transactions of of the current scope.

Comment: Yep, the problem presented is that I cannot control the `SELECT`s.

Comment: Did you tried the WITH(NOLOCK) on the SELECT statements outside the transaction scope? That will solve your problem.

Comment: Please read the question. I have no access to the `SELECT` statements,  and I just told you before. You're not understanding the question.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you, next time specify that you can't change  or modify the `SELECT` statement, 'access' word was misleading.

Comment: Probably I didn't express myself properly. My bad.