# Understanding the NOLOCK hint

Tags: sql, sql-server, transaction-isolation, nolock

Let's say I have a table with 1,000,000 rows and running a `SELECT * FROM TableName` on this table takes around 10 seconds to return the data.

*Without* a NOLOCK statement (putting to one side issues around dirty reads) would this query lock the table for 10 seconds meaning that no other process could read or write to the table?

I am often informed by DBAs then when querying live data to diagnose data issues I should use NOLOCK to ensure that I don't lock the table which may cause issues for users. Is this true?

Comment: This is a classic 'it depends' question!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686724/sql-when-should-you-use-with-nolock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NOLOCK` table hint will cause that no shared locks will be taken for the table in question; same with `READUNCOMMITTED` isolation level, but this time applies not to a single table but rather to everything involved. So, the answer is 'no, it won't lock the table'. Note that possible schema locks will still be held even with readuncommitted.

Not asking for shared locks the read operation will potentially read dirty data (updated but not yet committed) and non-existent data (updated, but rolled back), transactionally inconsistent in any case, and migh even skip the whole pages as well (in case of page splits happening simultaneously with the read operation).

Specifying either `NOLOCK` or `READUNCOMMITTED` is not considered a good practice. It will be faster, of course. Just make sure you're aware of consequences.

Also, support for these hints in UPDATE and DELETE statements will be removed in a future version, according to docs.

Comment: Are you sure support for these statements will be removed? I thought it was only being removed from UPDATE and DELETE statements (Why anyone would ever use it for those anyway is beyond me), and both will still work for SELECT statements. I am not sure I agree with the notion that *"Specifying either NOLOCK or READUNCOMMITTED is not considered a good practice"*, I will concede the way it is commonly used is bad, but the use of it itself I don't think is bad if you know what you are doing. It is kind of like seeing people eat soup with a fork, and then saying using a fork is bad practice.

Comment: You're correct about removal, just for the updates and deletes. And I still think it's not a good practice, surely not in the context of the question. If people have blocking issues, let them use RCSI. Unfortunatelly, if there's a NOLOCK hink with RCSI, query will not read from version store but rather the uncommitted value instead.

Comment: In the context of the question perhaps as the OP has locking issues, I am just saying it has it's places, but as you said, as long as you are fully aware of the consequences. An example would be my Boss comes out and says how many of our customers have an email address? He is unlikely to care whether it is or 449,000 or 451,000 - 450,000 is good enough for him (or her) and that allows for 2,000 dirty reads, without causing any locking issues.

Comment: Hi, to clarify there are no known locking issues. The DBA's concern is that whilst I run a long running query e.g. "Find out how many customers are named 'Smith'." it may affect active users on the web application.

Comment: It might interfere slightly with others' write operations if it takes a shared table lock.

Comment: That's what I was looking for but is there any way to know what lock it will take?

Comment: Locking is dynamic, defaults to row-level locks but if a substantial number of single row-level lock was taken (somewhere around 5000+) the lock manager will, to conserve resources and actually speed things up, escalate to table or partition level. You can affect it with hints. The right answer is to not use `select *`, to index properly, and code well.

Answer (score 1):

Your query will try to obtain a table level lock as you're asking for all the data. So yes it will be held for the duration of the query and all other processes trying to acquire Exclusive locks on that table with be put on wait queues. Processes that are also trying to read from that table will not be blocked.

Any diagnosis performed on a live system should done with care and using the NOLOCK hint will allow you to view data without creating any contention for users.

EDIT: As pointed out update locks are compatible with shared locks. So won't be blocked by the read process.

Comment: Thanks. I am reading conflicting things about this. Some blogs are saying that the locks are applied a row at a time and released straight away - other people seem to say that all of the rows are locked!

Comment: How locks are created and released depends on many factors. Assuming that you're using SQL Server or Sybase and your query runs in the READ COMMITTED ISOLATION LEVEL the locks will be held for the duration of the query. As you have queried the whole table it is highly probable that you will obtain a table lock. If SQL-Server is unable to obtain a table level lock, it will start to create row level locks, whilst periodically trying to obtain a table level lock. If it is able to promote to a table level lock then all the row level locks will released immediately.

Comment: Update locks are in fact compatible with shared locks.

Answer (score 1):

Even with `NOLOCK`, SQL Server can choose to override and obtain a lock, nevertheless. It is called a `QUERY **HINT**` for a reason. The sure fire way of avoiding locks would be to use `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` in the beginning of the session.

Comment: Very true, I read an article about this a while back (was it by Itzik Ben-Gan?). However most DBA's will tend to use NOLOCK. I think in 95% of circumstances NOLOCK hint will not yield locks.

Comment: SQL Server documentation seems to disagree with you: " NOLOCK Is equivalent to READUNCOMMITTED" (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx). Both are equaly dangerous.

Comment: Nothing dangerous about it. The question clearly states "(putting to one side issues around dirty reads)"