# Select all columns from one table and one from another where column equals variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the long title.

I have a statement which needs to grab all the columns from one row from BinConfig:

```
SELECT * 
FROM BinConfig WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE IssuerKey = @IssuerKey
```

But I also need to grab a single column from one row from `CardRangeGroup` also based on that `IssuerKey` column.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT 
    BinConfig.*, CardRangeGroup.Name 
FROM 
    BinConfig 
JOIN 
    CardRangeGroup WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE 
    @IssuerKey = BinConfig.IssuerKey 
    AND @IssuerKey = CardRangeGroup.IssuerKey
```

Which gives me a syntax error near `WHERE`. I've tried to find resources online, but everywhere I look I can't find anything explaining how to select rows based on a passed in variable. Any help?

Comment: You're missing the `ON` portion of the `JOIN` statement, SQL needs to know how the tables connect!

Comment: if this is MySQL then WITH(NOLOCK) is not supported. See this for equivalent http://itecsoftware.com/with-nolock-table-hint-equivalent-for-mysql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify how the tables should be joined. Try this:

```
SELECT BinConfig.*, CardRangeGroup.Name 
FROM BinConfig 
JOIN CardRangeGroup ON BinConfig.IssuerKey = CardRangeGroup.IssuerKey
WHERE @IssuerKey = CardRangeGroup.IssuerKey
```

The `with(nolock)` might not be needed (or a good idea) so I removed it.

Comment: I don't know how I forgot that, I'm fairly new to SQL and just learning about Join statements. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I tagged the question wrong. This is actually SQL-Server, is the `with(nolock)` function still supported?

Comment: @TobyCaulk Yes, but it might be bad to use though, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686724/sql-server-when-should-you-use-with-nolock and http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: I've heard how bad it can be, but I was told to use it so I still have to. Thank you for warning me though!

Answer (score 1):

try this , you don't need to use `where`

```
 SELECT BinConfig.*, CardRangeGroup.Name FROM BinConfig JOIN   
 CardRangeGroup
 ON CardRangeGroup.IssuerKey = BinConfig.IssuerKey AND @IssuerKey = CardRangeGroup.IssuerKey
```

Comment: Sure, the _where_ clause is optional, but it makes the intent clear though (in my opinion).

Comment: sorry, I dint mean to offend. I was just saying.