# SQL job loading data into portal

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Can someone help me on this?
Am working on a portal(Website) where all the data comes from another application. I load those data into my application's database table using a SQL Job on hourly basis everyday. The real problem is when the job runs and the data gets started to load into the portal. My portal's behavior is bad. i.e. when a user opens the portal when the job is running he see data mismatch/slow performance etc. But everything becomes normal once the job runs successfully.

Job takes 7 minutes to get complete and the real problem occurs during that 7 mins.

Please help, Thank you in advance.

Comment: no way to help you.  How are you "loading" the data. Are you using SSIS -- a C# program, 10000 people at keyboards?  We are going to need more detail.

Comment: @Hogan Sorry for that, Yes we use SSIS to load the data. am happy to provide more details if needed

Comment: Probably need more details, but if you website is not using `with (nolock)` you might find that helps (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686724/sql-server-when-should-you-use-with-nolock).  Other than that without specific SQL that is slow or slows down the system it is basically impossible to help you.

Comment: Thank you @Hogan i have 12 job steps that runs in portal. out of those only one step takes long time. That is where the portal behaves bad. Let me check whether my website uses with(nolock)