# Select and insert at the same moment SQL 2016

Tags: sql, deadlock

I have simple table in my application where is

> ID | VALUE | DATE | ITEMID

All the time some items are inserting data threw my webservice to this table. I am inserting only data that is 5 or more minutes old. At the same time when I am using my web application I am selecting some max, min and current values for items. From time to time I got

> Transaction (Process ID 62) was deadlocked on lock resources with
>   another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction.

Is there any chance to get data and for that moment when I am selecting, don't care about inserts?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using SQL Server 2016:

**Problem:**

When we write a `SELECT` statement, shared locks are held on resources - say the `TableX` from which max, min and current values are being selected. Now for this moment if you `INSERT` data in these locked tables (`TableX`), then because `INSERT` requires an exclusive lock on the resource (`TableX`), the `INSERT` statement will wait for the `SELECT` to finish.

**Solution:**

As suggested in posts below, we can use `WITH (NOLOCK)` or `WITH (READ UNCOMMITTED)` table hints so that `SELECT` statements don't hold a lock on the underlying resources (`TableX`). But the problem is, this `SELECT` might read uncommitted data that was changed during a transaction and then later was rolled back to its initial state (also called reading dirty data).

If you want to make sure that the `SELECT` only reads committed data and also doesn't block the `INSERT`s to write to `TableX`, then at database level `SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `with(nolock)` hint, 
This will get you uncommitted data.

See the answer here
[What is "with (nolock)" in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686724/what-is-with-nolock-in-sql-server)

And here
http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/using-with-nolock

Comment: if it does i'll appreciate if you'll mark it as the selected answer :)

Comment: until now client didn't sent any requests that problem is still existsing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `SELECT` query to avoid deadlocks as:

```
SELECT ITEMID, MAX(VALUE), MIN(VALUE)
FROM table_name WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY ITEMID, DATE
```