# Join two tables, each with multiple rows with the same key values on just the latest version of each

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to list the codes and descriptions that are used in a "person" table.  There are many codes in the "code_table" but I don't want to list unused codes.

I have a "person" table that has a record for each time a person is changed... in particular, I'm interested in the "person_code" field.  Every person record has a date_revised value that indicates when the change was made.  The person table has an identity primary key (person_id) and a person identifier (person_int) for each person.

I have a "code_table" which has records for each time it's changed, again containing a date_revised field.  It has a "code_type" field that matches person_code in the person table and "code_data" which is the description of the code. Code_table also has a identity primary key and an identifier (code_group + code_type)

So, the data might look like:
person:

```
person_id person_int person_code person_first person_last date_revised
1 1234 JPM John Doe 1/2/2021
232 1234 JPM Johnathan Doe 2/11/2021
432 1234 PM Johnny Doe 4/24/2021
```

code_table:

```
code_id code_group code_type code_description date_revised
2 person_code PM Project Manager 1/9/2021
32 person_code PM Senior Project Manager 3/16/2021
```

So, I'm looking for the "PM" and "Senior Project Manager" code to be listed.  If there were only one row for each, I could simply join them with:

```
select distinct code_type,code_data from person 
join code_table on code_group='person_code' and person_code = code_type  
order by code_data
```

Obviously, I get a ton of duplicates. So, how do I write a query so that I link the latest person record with the latest code_table record and list the latest code_table values? The result should show only the unique code_table entries.

EDIT:
I've never used db fiddle and didn't see how to save it.  Here are the statements to create a sample:

```
create table person (
person_id int,
person_int int, person_code varchar(55),
person_first varchar(55),
person_last varchar(55),
date_revised datetime)
insert into person select 1, 1234, 'JPM', 'John', 'Doe', '1/2/2021'
insert into person select 12, 1234, 'JPM', 'Johnathn', 'Doe', '2/2/2021'
insert into person select 2231, 1234, 'PM', 'Johnny', 'Doe', '2/2/2021'
insert into person select 2232, 222, 'PM', 'Billy', 'Bob', '2/2/2021'
select * from person
create table code_table (
code_id int,
code_group varchar(55),
code_type  varchar(55),
code_description  varchar(55),
date_revised datetime)
insert into code_table select 1, 'person_code', 'JPM', 'Junior Project Manager', '1/9/2021'
insert into code_table select 2, 'person_code', 'PM', 'Project Manager', '1/9/2021'
insert into code_table select 3, 'person_code', 'MGR', 'Manager', '1/9/2021'
insert into code_table select 32, 'person_code', 'PM', 'Senior Project Manager', '2/9/2021'
insert into code_table select 33, 'person_code', 'SUP', 'Supervisor', '2/19/2021'
select * from code_table
```

The only thing that should result is "PM Senior Project Manager"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking that this gets really complex. What would be wrong with creating two views that only select the latest rows and then use a regular join to get the data?

```
create view view_code_table 
as 
WITH ct AS 
(select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code_group,code_seq,code_type,code_language ORDER BY date_revised DESC) AS rn from code_table) 
SELECT * FROM ct WHERE rn = 1

create view view_person
as 
WITH p AS 
(select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY org_int,person_int ORDER BY date_revised DESC) AS rn from person) 
SELECT * FROM p WHERE rn = 1
```

Then join the views with whatever constraints you want.

```
select distinct code_type,code_data from view_person 
join view_code_table on code_group='person_code' and person_code = code_type  
order by code_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the date_revised will be unique per person, I think the following code will work with you:

```
select distinct
    c.code_type,
    c.code_data 
from person p with(nolock)
inner join code_table c on c.code_group='person_code' and p.person_code = c.code_type  
inner join (
    select person_int, max(date_revised) date_revised from person a with(nolock) group by a.person_int
    ) x on x.date_revised = p.date_revised and x.person_int = p.person_int
order by c.code_data
```

Comment: I think you might find this instructive. [What is “with (nolock)” in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686724/what-is-with-nolock-in-sql-server)

Comment: I know that I use with(nolock) so much, but it's really useful when you have simple systems and a lot of data.

Comment: That code is almost it but I wasn't clear in my question.  I only want to see the unique code table entries. This shows for each person so I edited it and added "distinct".  Now, it shows only the unique code but I only want to see the latest code_table entry.  It's showing "PM Project Manager" and "PM Senior Project Manager"... I only want to see the last one.