# WITH(NOLOCK) in SQL Server

Tags: sql

I hope you are doing well,

I have a question, to use the table hint WITH(NOLOCK) in the last versions of SQL Server is required to use explicit in select sentence, I mean I have to specify it?

Thanks.

Comment: No, the latest SQL Server is able to read your mind and will automatically use WITH(NOLOCK) when you would want it to be used.

Comment: @GSerg not every one understands irony and sarcasm

Comment: Sarcasm aside,  make sure you understand the implications of using  nolock.

Comment: i think you should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686724/what-is-with-nolock-in-sql-server  and only use it when actually needed, bit you still have to specify which isolation level you want